# Add character in the middle of a string

Tags: string, cakephp, split, character, addition

I have a list of six digit codes (some are 7). What I need is to put a space after the fourth character of each code, to make it more readable in my views. It would be like:

```
234201
234202
234203
```

to

```
2342 01
2342 02
2342 03
```

Is there any way to do this quickly in cake php? Other than doing all the work with tail and other functions that would require some more coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php):

```
substr_replace('123456', ' ', 4, 0); // returns '1234 56'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a more elegant solution to this, but at least it works.

Just appends a space in between to parts of the string.

```
$string           = "123456";
$formatted_string = substr($string, 0, 4) . " " . substr($string, 4);
```

`$formatted_string` should now be `1234 56`

Answer (score 1):

You can always build a small reusable function like this:

```
//adds a character to a string at a specific position
function addChar($string, $char, $pos) {
    $newString = substr($string, 0, $pos) . $char . substr($string, $pos);
    return $newString;
}
```

To use:

```
$myString = "234201";
$myAlteredString = addChar($myString , " ", 4);
```